# How to access iTunes podcast playlists on iOS 11

Tags: ios, itunes, podcasts, podcasts.app

I just upgraded to iOS 11 (took me a while to be ready to say goodbye to some of my heavily used 32-bit non-upgraded apps). Something I use my iPhone for A LOT is listening to my podcast smart playlists... they sync to my iTunes so I listen some on my computer and then continue on my phone. After upgrading to iOS 11, they seem to be gone.

Is there a trick to syncing from iOS to iTunes for podcast listen status?

Comment: I’ve split off the “software recommendation” portion of this. We do welcome recommendation questions so feel free to ask a stand-alone - what third party apps allow this sort of syncing between Mac and iOS. Either way - this will get answers if you can enable this or if you can’t (you might get conflicting info since not everyone may know how it works or the sync may be partial )